# Push notification for distributed profile is not working.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, app-store

Hi I have submitted one app ,in development mode push notification is working,

i just follow the steps in this site  `www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1`
but ,in distributed profile i made following things

```
1. $ openssl x509 -in aps_production.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem

2.$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12
Enter Import Password: 
MAC verified OK
Enter PEM pass phrase: 
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:



3. cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem

4.$ telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.232.226...
Connected to gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.

5.$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey.pem:
```

but I don't know why when i send push notification its showing

"Connected to `APNS` Message successfully delivered "   but no one getting notification through live app(app in app store).

Please help me

Comment: I would recommend you start by connecting a device to your mac, initializing the app and check the device log.  It should say whether or not APNS is correctly authorized.

Comment: In Appstore certificate Pushnotification doesn't work. Use Ad-Hoc It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had also follow the same tutorial and was facing the same problem.
Try to change the URL for production.(Add hoc/Production)

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60,
    STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

Hope this will help.